# strange behaviour of MVC routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I was reading How MVC routing work from **[Routing Basics in ASP.NET MVC](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/624181/Routing-Basics-in-ASP-NET-MVC)**.

It says

> Additional URL Parameters other than {controller} and {action} are
>   available to be passed as arguments to the selected Action method.

So I created an action with parameter name `controller` of `string` type.

```
public ActionResult About(string controller, string test)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }
```

When I watch value of `controller`, It was **Home**, Which was my controller name.

But when I tried to access to from these two method, Then it return null. **Why** ?

- `Request.Params["controller"]`
- `Request.QueryString["controller"]`

If it is does not picking value of **controller** parameter from above methods, Then from where it get **controller** value.

I used this action link to invoke action.

```
 <a href="@Url.Action("About", "home", new { controller  ="Hello" , test ="Amit"})">Check</a>
```

Comment: What you mean by 'controller value'?

Comment: @ihavenokia : it is parameter name of action named About

Comment: I reviewed and tested `Url.Action` given above in a fiddle and the link helper URL translated to `/Home/About?test=Amit`, dismissing `Hello` string (but strangely `Hello` captured successfully in action method). Also seems that `Request.Params["test"]` and `Request.QueryString["test"]` assignments resulted as `Amit` string.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto : But if you put debugger and watch value of parameter `controller` then It will show Home.  It does not capture `Hello` but `Home`

Comment: Yes, that's exactly happened on my testing: `controller` argument in `About` action method contains `Hello` string, which not available when calling `Request.Params["controller"]` & `Request.QueryString["controller"]`. Seems that something inside `routeValues` object parser inside action helper messed up and require further investigation.

Comment: That is the expected behavior. When building the url, the values of the `controllerName`and `actionName` parameters are merged with your `routeValues` parameter. The `controllerName` value overwrites the `controller` value in your `routeValues. You can inspect the [source code here](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/UrlHelper.cs)

Comment: And if your omit the `controllerName` - `@Url.Action("About",  new { controller  ="Hello" , test ="Amit"})"` you will see that it generates `../Hello/About?test=Amit` which would result in a 404 (assuming you do not have a `HelloController`

Answer (score 0):

You can get controller and action value using

string actionName = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();

string controllerName = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();

Comment: That is not what OP is asking